# Recursive Call in Javascript Class (requestanimationframe)

Tags: javascript, three.js, this

I have a simple class that I am using to manage scenes in three.js. I am having issues with the requestAnimationFrame loop finding the function reference. I know I am missing something fundamental here, trapped in some *this* nightmare. Do I need to use bind or call to pass the this reference to requestAnimationFrame?

```
var THREE = THREE || {};
var SceneBuddy = SceneBuddy || {};

SceneBuddy = function(scene, camera) {
    this.scene = scene;
    this.camera = camera;
    this.sceneClock = new THREE.Clock();
    this.renderer = {};
    this.resolution = {};
    this.controls = {};
};
//Start Animate
SceneBuddy.prototype.startAnimate = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(this.startAnimate); //this does not work, type error
    this.render.call(this);
};
//Render Function
SceneBuddy.prototype.render = function() {
    var delta = this.sceneClock.getDelta();
    this.controls.update(delta);
    this.renderer.render(this.scene,this.camera);
};

//Setup Renderer
SceneBuddy.prototype.initRenderer = function(resolution) {
    if (!Detector.webgl) {
        Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
        return;
    }
    else {
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            antialias: true,
            preserveDrawingBuffer: true
        });
        renderer.setSize(resolution.x, resolution.y);
        renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
        this.resolution = resolution;
        this.renderer = renderer;
    }
};
```

I am using currently using SceneBuddy like this :

```
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 100000);
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var sceneBuddy = new SceneBuddy(scene, camera);
  sceneBuddy.initRenderer({x: 940, y: 400});
  sceneBuddy.attachRenderer(container); //attaches renderer to dom element
  sceneBuddy.initControls();
  sceneBuddy.startAnimate(); // broken.
```

Comment: How are you instantiating SceneBuddy?

Comment: Could you add the full code of how you're setting the `requestAnimationFrame` function on the global object? Also: I'd expect the `startAnimate` function to accept a timestamp parameter

Comment: requestAnimationFrame is provided by the shim included with three.js. Not sure I follow your suggestion about providing a timestamp?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `bind` when passing a function to specify what `this` will be when the function is called:

```
SceneBuddy.prototype.startAnimate = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(this.startAnimate.bind(this));
    this.render();
};
```

Comment: This works, thank you. Out of curiosity, is something like this necessary : this.render.call(this); or is that redundant? Previously this.render() wasn't working unless I called like above, once in the render function, the this context was not defined. Could have just been a glitch from the requestAnimationFrame breaking.

Comment: I can't think of an example where `this.render.call(this)` would work when `this.render()` doesn't - they do the same thing.  If you don't bind the rAF callback then `this` will be the global object/window which probably doesn't have a `render` function